# AES encrypted password in UTF-8

Tags: c++, utf-8, openssl, aes

My application receives UTF-16 string as password, which should be saved post encryption in the database with UTF-8 encoding. I'm taking following actions for it

1. Take input password in wstring (UTF-16)
2. Reinterpret this password using reinterpret_cast to unsigned char *.
3. Use step 2 password and encrypt it using AES_cbc_encrypt, which returns unsigned char *
4. Convert step 3 output to wstring (UTF-16)
5. Convert wstring to UTF-8 using Poco's UnicodeConvertor class. Save this UTF-8 string in the database

Is this the correct way of saving AES encrypted password? Please suggest if there is a better way

Comment: After encryption, you've just got binary data. *Don't* try to interpret it as UTF-16 text... base64 encode it instead, or store it as binary. (Having said this, you shouldn't be just encrypting it anyway - you should be using hashing of some kind to make it irreversible.)

Comment: It is somewhat likely that the raw bytes will not be valid UTF-16 code points. There is a reserved range D800-DFFF and pockets of unallocated codes.

Comment: Do you really need the unencrypted password later?

Comment: Yes. In case a user wants to see her password later

Comment: @Abhinav nooo. Nononnono. Do you really think your users will thank you when your database gets hacked and all your users' *plaintext* passwords are leaked? If you are going to store password, do it *properly*. Securely salted and hashed.

Comment: "Reinterpret this password using reinterpret_cast to unsigned char *." - For interoperability, convert it to UTF-8 before you do anything else. As UTF-8, your derivations will be consistent on Java, .Net, C++, etc.

Comment: As Jalf said, that's a bad design from a security engineering perspective. User's *don't* get to see their passwords later because they picked them earlier. The only person who benefits later is the bad guy. I'm mentioning it too because it's really bad.

Comment: -1 for storing passwords instead of hashes. What you are trying is just catastrophic from the security view point. How could we trust you that you secure your database correctly. Do you have trustworthy software there (think about the heartbleed attack). The bottom line is that for authentication purposes passwords are stored hashed by a *secure* hash algorithm (like bcrypt, scrypt or PBKDF2).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on your requirements you might want to consider first encoding the string to UTF-8 and then encrypting it.
Advantage of this approach is, that the hash stored in the DB is based on a binary format that is independent of endianess.
Using UTF-16 you usually need to deal with endianess when you have clients on different systems implemented in different programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

I think you'd be much better off converting the encripted password to hex digits or to base-64 encoding. This way you're guaranteed to have no weird or illegal UTF-16 symbols, nor will you have \n, \r or \t in your UTF-8. The converted text will be somewhat larger - hope it's not a big deal.